# How to fully customize WebStorm theme?

Tags: themes, webstorm

Is there a way to fully customize WebStorm's theme to change the code panels, navigation bars and menu panels?

I've seen a lot of screenshots on Google of this, but my WebStorm has a default-white theme on every panels, and a tomorrow night theme for the code.

Comment: Solved ! View->Quick change theme-> switch LOOK AND FEEL -> Darcula

Comment: add your answer to your question :)

Answer (score 1):

View -> Quick Switch Theme -> Switch Look and Feel